# D3.csv output has false values

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, queue

I'm using d3.csv to load a quite large dataset. The number of rows is not too big (500000), but the number of columns might be quite large (113). 
My current data is something like this:

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5
1,2,NA,NA,NA
1,4,5,2,3
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter the values and only get the columns that have a number. This is my function parseRows

```
function parseRows (data,i){
  //get values of columns
  var _values = Object.values(data);

  //filter values and return only the ones with numbers
  var filteredValues = _values.filter(function(d){return d!=="NA"});

  var _endValue = +filteredValues[filteredValues.length-1];

  return {
    startValue : +data.v1,
    endValue : _endIntersection,
    values : filteredIntersections
   }

}
```

The code works perfectly until row 498544. From that moment on, the values that are loaded are not real, all of them are wrong. I've checked the dataset and they just don't exist in that csv. And if I console log _filteredValues,_endValue, etc. inside parseRows when the index is 498544 or 498545, etc. the values that are being parsed are the ones in the csv.

This dataset is being load through a queue function:

```
var queue = d3.queue()
   .defer(d3.csv, "data/othervalues.csv", parseOtherValues)
   .defer(d3.csv, "data/values/values_set_1.csv",parseRows)
   .await(dataloaded);
```

And the problem is seen in dataloaded. Any idea why this might be happening? Is there a limit for d3.csv?

Row 498545 looks like this (with commas instead

```
"1337", "1112", "1337", "1226", "1248", "1272", "1297", "1322", "1344", "1359", "1380", "1405", "1432", "1454", "1481", "1507", "1534", "1581", "1614", "1641", "1665", "1688", "1707", "1726", "1749", "1773", "1653", "1502", "1417", "1336", "1247", "1188", "1166", "1004", "1025", "1048", "1064", "1088", "1112", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA"
```

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried reducing the CSV to just those two lines in question? Could you set up a [mcve]?

Comment: Hi, I've tested the code reducing the CSV to those lines and it works, there's no error. I can't show you an example that produces the error because that would mean creating a fiddle with a CSV of at least 498545 rows. The current dataset I am using is from a project and it cannot be shared. Sorry

Comment: Can you share the rows around that position (498545)? I can tell you that D3 sets no limit for the number of rows in a CSV. If there is a limit, that comes from the browser, the server, the computer's memory or whatever, but not from D3 source code.

Comment: Also, **where** are you calling that `parseRows` function? Is that a row conversion function?

Comment: `parseRows` are called in the queue function, it's the callback function of d3.csv. All the files are stored locally. It might be my computer, but although the file is big, it's not _that big_

Comment: If the number of columns in your CSV is 113 and you correctly quoted that line 498545, then your CSV is malformed because there are only 99 fields on that line.